# create mongoose schema with array of objects

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb

Even though the question have been asked numerous time none of the answers  have any idea to help me .
This is my mongoose Schema

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const { Schema } = mongoose;
    const recipeSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    imagePath: { type: String, required: true },
     ingredients:[
    {
            name:{type:String, required:true},
            amount:{type:Number,required:true   }
    }

]

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Recipe",recipeSchema);
```

what i need is to get the data from angular and store it to my database using node

```
   const Recipe = require('../models/recipe.model');
   const recipeCtrl={};

   recipeCtrl.CreateRecipeServer =async(req, res, next)=>{
   if(!req.file) {
     return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Upload fail'});
   }

else {
 let ingredientArray=new Array()
 ingredientArray.push(req.body.ingredients)

req.body.imageUrl = 'http://192.168.0.7:3000/images/' + req.file.filename;


const recipe=new Recipe({
name:req.body.name,
description:req.body.description,
imagePath:req.body.imageUrl,
ingredients:[
  {
    name:ingredientArray,
  amount:ingredientArray }
]
 
 });
await recipe.save();

}
```

Everything except the ingredients array works perfectly/as i require.

I am getting the ingredients as an array from formdata so it have to be JSON.stringfied inorder to append with the form. So what i am getting at backend is string . eg

```
 **[{"name":"dasdasd","amount":2},{"name":"fsfsd","amount":2},{"name":"sdfsdgd","amount":3}]**
```

this is a string. Any ideas on how to convert it and store to database

Comment: use JSON.parse()

Comment: when using json .parse this is what I get                                                                         
       [
        [
    { name: 'dasdasd', amount: 2 },
    { name: 'fsfsd', amount: 2 },
    { name: 'sdfsdgd', amount: 3 }
    ]
  ]

Comment: when you use json.parse it convert to json so you need to get first element of json parse
for example `JSON.parse(data)[0]` then insert in database

Comment: thanks a lot it worked finally , 3 days i was behind it

Comment: do you want to make it answer  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JSON.parse` and choose first element of that

```
JSON.parse(data)[0]
```

Comment: JSON.parse(data) is only required